# RenderScript Gives me strange Error

Tags: android, renderscript

I'm using RenderScript but it gives me this error when i want to use it:

```
 Process: com.example.shahryar.ripplerenderscript, PID:1794
 android.support.v8.renderscript.RSRuntimeException: Loading of ScriptC script failed.
 at android.support.v8.renderscript.ScriptC.<init>(ScriptC.java:61)
 at com.example.shahryar.ripplerenderscript.ScriptC_ripple.<init>(ScriptC_ripple.java:0)
```

It should work. but it gives me error that script failed i don't know why.
But I found out that if i change the targetSdkVersion 23 to targetSdkVersion 19 there is no error in genymotion anymore.
I'm using the following in gradle too:

```
renderscriptTargetApi 18
renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```

now i want to know why it gives me an error when i change the targetSdkVersion to anything higher than 19?

Comment: Which `minSdkVersion` are you using?